# c# - Parsing an odd string concatenation to float

Tags: c#, string, parsing, floating-point

I'm working in C# and trying to parse out the floats on each side of the "w" from the following string:

```
"10.3w20.5"
```

I want to have the floats available to use as floats in an equation. How do I accomplish this?

I tried splitting the string by length but then realized that the values on each side could be variable in length.

Comment: So, what have you tried so far?

Comment: What have you tried? looks like a split + parse should do this easily enough...?

Comment: Sorry. Yes, I forgot to mention I tried splitting the string by length but then realized that those 2 values on each side could be variable in length.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
var floats = "10.3w20.5".Split('w').Select(s => Convert.ToSingle(s));
```

Comment: That gives a sequence, which can be a pain to work with - as a very minor suggestion, I'd look at `var floats = Array.ConvertAll("10.3w20.5".Split('w'), Convert.ToSingle);` personally.

Comment: @MarcGravell: What about appending `.ToArray()`? Would that made a difference to your call?

Answer (score 3):

The only thing to add to avalable answers, is what usually people forget to mantion in conversion mnagement. If you're going to operate in *multiculture* environment, pay attention on [Culture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w7zs80w4.aspx) you use to store and convert data to.

```
public static float ToSingle(
    string value,
    IFormatProvider provider
)
```

I would say, even if you're not going to operate in *multiculture* environment, *it's always a good to pay attention on this*.